# Overriding get() method in Django UpdateView gives 'str' has no attribute get error

Tags: python, django

I have a Stats model which is related to Django User model with a OneToOne Field.
I have an UpdateView:

```
class StatsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Stats
    fields = ('stat1', 'stat2', 'stat3')
```

It works fine, but any User is allowed to modify the Stats related to any User, I want a User to onlyupdate the Stats related to him.
So I override the get() method in StatsUpdateView like this:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user != Stats.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).user:  #checks if the user logged in is the same user related to the Stats with the onetoone field. Works fine.
            return redirect('homepage:home')
        else:  # if the user match, he can access the update view for his own stats
            print('user match')
            return reverse('user:updatestats', kwargs={'pk': kwargs['pk']})
```

The code runs fine until the else statement, 'user match' gets printed into the console but I get this error while running the server:
**'str' object has no attribute 'get'**

Here's the path:

```
path('updatestats/<int:pk>/', StatisticheUpdateView.as_view(), name='updatestats')
```

EDIT complete Treceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\scalfarino\PycharmProjects\openyourmind2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exceptio
n.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\scalfarino\PycharmProjects\openyourmind2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py",
 line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\scalfarino\PycharmProjects\openyourmind2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjackin
g.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Hi @CCima - I think that you will have to add more information for people to be able to help you - are you able to provide the complete Django debug message?

Comment: use [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), enter permissions page and read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a function view like this:

```
def update_stats(request, pk):
    stats= get_object_or_404(Stats, pk=pk)
    if request.user == stats.user:
        form = StatsForm(request.POST or None)  # just make a form as you need
        if form.is_valid():
            stats.stat1= form.cleaned_data.get('stat1')
            # etc
            stats.save()
            return redirect('/yoururl')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'update.html', context)  # render your template
     else:
         return redirect('homepage:home')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

use **HttpResponseRedirect**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user:updatestats', kwargs={'pk': kwargs['pk']}))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: Even with the request parameter I get the same output and error, also I can already access request with self.request

Comment: now gives a 'Toomanyredirects' error, the reason I use reverse() instead of redirect is to avoid this error

Comment: try **redirect** instead of **HttpResponseRedirect**

Comment: It was my first option, gives a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Comment: Update, using redirect gets the view to redirect to itself in an infinite loop, 'user match' gets printed into the console many times until the server crash